Subtracting Cell Values
I'm new to all of this so forgive me if this is too basic.
I have a table and I'm trying to subtract the contents of "Days Absent" from "Days Present"
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
<table class="table grid">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="left" width="100">Days Absent</th>
<th class="left" width="100">Days Present</th>
<th class="left" width="100">Days Membership</th>
<th class="left" width="100">Days Enrolled</th>
<th class="left" width="200">Daily Attendance Pct</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>~(daily.att.count;;A,J,G,CT;08/30/23;06/14/24)
</td>
<td>**Days Membership - Days Absent**</td>
<td>~(*DM;08/30/23;06/14/24;format=##0.0) </td>
<td>~(aggmemdays;08/30/23;06/14/24;format=##0.0)</td>
<td>~(*evaluate round((~(*DA;08/01/~(f.add;~(curyearid);1990);~(f.currentdate);format=##0.0)/~(*DM;8/01/~(f.add;~(curyearid);1990);~(f.currentdate);format=##0.0) )*100.0,1)) %
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

As I said, I'm new to this so I first just tried subtracting the values
~(*DM;08/30/23;06/14/24;format=##0.0) - ~(daily.att.count;;A,J,G,CT;08/30/23;06/14/24)
but that didn't calculate - it just showed it as "value - value"
I've looked around and some say adding variables, but I don't know where I would need to add them.
Thanks,
